# How can I use Pik for Ruby in Git Bash on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, git, git-bash, pik

I'm running multiple versions of Ruby (and Rails) on Windows and use Pik to switch between them. At the **command line**, I'm able to call

```
> pik list
186: ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]
192: ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

to get a list of ruby versions available, and use

```
> pik 192

> ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

to make ruby 1.9.2 the active version:

I am not able to do the same in **git bash**:

```
 $ pik list
 sh.exe": pik: command not found
```

and the version of ruby is still 1.8.6

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]
```

It seems like git bash can't see the path to pik. Is there a way to alter the path within git bash or is there another way to run pik in git bash?

Comment: Under git, can you run `echo $PATH`, and under windows, can you run `PATH`? Also, can you run `gem env`?

Comment: Yes to echo $PATH and Yes to gem env.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that. Run those commands, and add the output of them to your question (minus any stuff that you consider private).

Answer (score 10):

The last answer is correct as far as it goes. However, on Windows systems the $USERPROFILE environment variable is set to something like: C:\Documents and Settings\username.

The spaces in the path cause the command to be interpreted improperly. This is better:

```
[[ -s "$USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc" ]] && source "$USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc"
```

Note the quotes around the paths in the code snippet above.

Additionally, your .bashrc file (or .bash_profile file) should be located within the directory specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable, e.g. - C:\Documents and Settings\username.

Comment: Also if you install Pik on a different drive (e.g. D:), you also need to edit the .pikrc file located under the .pik forlder under your user profile so that the pik_path points to the right drive. E.g.: pik_path=d:/pik

Comment: Also if you install 1.9.2 separately using the Windows installer, you will need to edit the .pik/config.yml and add a gem_home setting pointing to the 1.9.2 gem home:
:gem_home: !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

Comment: Ok so I ended up creating a Gist for the 3 key changes needed: https://gist.github.com/1239600

Answer (score 3):

I had to edit .bash_profile and .pikrc

.bash_profile:

```
[[ -s "$USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc" ]] && source "$USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc"
```

.pikrc

```
#!/bin/sh
pik_path="/c/Program Files/pik"

function pik  {
  "$pik_path/pik_runner.exe" pik.sh $@
  [[ -s "$USERPROFILE/.pik/pik.sh" ]] && source "$USERPROFILE/.pik/pik.sh"
}
```

Having quotes around the paths is only necessary if you have spaces in the path (like "Program Files").

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you have the latest version of Pik installed (0.2.8), with it. open your user profile `.bash_profile` or similar under Git Bash and ensure it contains the following code:

```
[[ -s $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc ]] && source $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc
```

From there you should be able to invoke pik from the Git Bash terminal.

Hope that helps

Comment: not having quotes around `source $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc` gave me trouble. So `"source $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc"` fixed those...